# How to tell if QHostAddress is IPv4 or IPv6 in Qt5?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, ipv6, ipv4

I can create a `QHostAddress` objects like this:

```
QHostAddress addr_ip4("127.0.0.1");
QHostAddress addr_ip6("::1/128");
```

And test their properties like this:

```
qDebug() << "addr_ip4.isNull() =      " << addr_ip4.isNull();
qDebug() << "addr_ip4.isLoopback() =  " << addr_ip4.isLoopback();
qDebug() << "addr_ip4.isMulticast() = " << addr_ip4.isMulticast();

qDebug() << "addr_ip6.isNull() =      " << addr_ip6.isNull();
qDebug() << "addr_ip6.isLoopback() =  " << addr_ip6.isLoopback();
qDebug() << "addr_ip6.isMulticast() = " << addr_ip6.isMulticast();
```

But... how can I tell which of the addresses are in fact **IPv4** and which are **IPv6**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling [QHostAddress::protocol()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhostaddress.html#protocol) will return a [QAbstractSocket::NetworkLayerProtocol enum](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#NetworkLayerProtocol-enum) that specifies if the address is IPv4, IPv6, both, or other.